# autocomplete not recognised in IE9

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My issue is that the following code works fine in firefox and chrome but does not work in IE9. It says location is undefined or null.

My autocomplete code is as follows:

```
$( "#id_location" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {

$.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'food.views.search_location' %}",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{  
                    maxRows: 5,
                    starts_with: request.term,
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.location, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,       

        focus: function(event,ui){
    //prevent value insert on focus
    $("#id_location").val(ui.item.label);
      return false; //Prevent widget from inserting value
      },

    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#id_location').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#id_locationID').val(ui.item.value);
        return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
        },


    });
```

My backened code is as follows:

```
def search_location(request):
"""
Jason data for location
search autocomplete
"""
    q = request.GET['starts_with']
    r = request.GET['maxRows']
    ret = []
    listlocation = USCities.objects.filter(name__istartswith=q)[:r]
    for i in listlocation:
        ret.append({'label':i.name+','+i.state.name+' '+i.state.abbr,'value':i.id})

    ret = {'location':ret}
    data = simplejson.dumps(ret)
    return HttpResponse(data,
        content_type='application/json; charset=utf8'
     )
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where you're getting the location undefined or null? In server side or in JS? Also can you tell where exactly in code the error happens?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

```
starts_with: request.term,
```

This is the last element in an object structure, and it has a comma at the end.

This is technically illegal in Javascript, but IE is the only browser that enforces it. This is why you'll have an error with it in IE but not other browsers.

The same error also occurs on line 33 (ie nearly at the end of the code), where you have a closing brace followed by an illegal comma `},` at the end of an object structure.

This error shows up easily if you validate your code in tools such as [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Hope that helps.